# Why can't underscore.js read the data?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

This is my js code:
**task.js**

```
var result = [{user: 'a'}, {'user': b}]
$('#cc_test').html(_.template($('#tpl_vgroup_row_test').html(), result))
```

**template.html**

```
<div id='cc_test'></div>
<script type="text/template" id="tpl_vgroup_row_test">
  <%= result %>
</script>
```

But chrome console shows me this:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: result is not defined
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try passing an object to `_.template` instead of just a value, like so

```js
var result = [{user: 'a'}, {'user': 'b'}]
$('#cc_test').html(_.template($('#tpl_vgroup_row_test').html(), {result: result}))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>

<div id='cc_test'></div>
<script type="text/template" id="tpl_vgroup_row_test">
  <%= result %>
  <%= result[0].user %>
  <%= result[1].user %> 
</script>
```